# Sockets -- Different bytes from python and java

Tags: java, python, sockets

I have been working on a networking project recently to revive a dead mmo game for personal learning, I have a python implementation which works to decode the game data using blowfish(pypi / pycryptodome) and would like to transfer this 'server' into a java project.

Initially using blowfish decryption in java (BouncyCastle and Cipher -- default) I was getting entirely different results between java and python. Through some research I found that java (along with most things) actually use blowfish-compat big endian.

This one python library seems to be the only one which correctly decodes the data. Next I decided to use a python asyncio server as a middle relay simply for encryption and decryption. The network flow now looks like this:

`GameClient -> Java SocketServer -> Python server (decryption) -> Java SocketServer`.

The original `Python` implementation results in these bytes in hex format:

```
32004a815f49367cc3691be26d7b668132506dc972d5a6bbad38299640c6e222c6e55096f50ff33711250675431633ca9ede
```

The Java implementation produces these results in hex format(using apache commons Hex.encodeHexString())

```
32004a815f49367cc3691be26d7b668132506dc972d5a6bbad38299640c6e222c6e5c65830d65f9b4d60eb26730685f486d7
```

Both of these hex representations are pre-blowfish decryption in Python they are just the raw bytes being sent from the game client.

My question is why do these bytes start off the same and then it seems java trails off? The python results are the correct results they are tested and work. I have tried wrapping the bytes in java in a buffer and then calling `flip()` however this did not produce the correct results either. Using another stackoverflow post (I do not have link I am sorry) I tried casting this byte[] into a BigInteger and that also did not produce the correct results.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Python Implementation

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import binascii
import blowfish
import ipaddress
import os
import struct
import sys

AUTH_BLOWFISHKEY = b"[;'.]94-31==-%&@!^+]\000"
bf = blowfish.Cipher(AUTH_BLOWFISHKEY, byte_order="little")


class EncryptionRelay(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.client = (transport.get_extra_info('peername')[0] + ":"    # IP
        + str(transport.get_extra_info('peername')[1]))             # port
        print("Connection from: " + self.client)


    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print("Connection closed: " + self.client)


    def data_received(self, data):
        print(data.hex()) #python output above
        pt = b''.join(bf.decrypt_ecb(data[2:]))
        self.transport.write(pt)

    def closeSocket(self, reason):
        print(reason)
        self.transport.close()


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coroutine = loop.create_server(EncryptionRelay, host=None, port=54556)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)

    for socket in server.sockets:
        print("Listening on: " + socket.getsockname()[0] + ":" +
        str(socket.getsockname()[1]))
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    server.close()
    loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
    loop.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Java Implementation

```
public AuthServer(int port) {
    serverGUI = new AuthServerGUI(port);

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        relay = new PythonEncryptionRelay(this);
        new Thread(relay).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            onConnection(socket); //sends an init packet to client -- irrelevant to question 

            byte[] incomingData = new byte[0];
            byte[] temp = new byte[1024];
            int k = -1;

            while((k = socket.getInputStream().read(temp, 0, temp.length)) > -1) {
                byte[] tbuff = new byte[incomingData.length + k];
                System.arraycopy(incomingData, 0, tbuff, 0, incomingData.length);
                System.arraycopy(temp, 0, tbuff, incomingData.length, k);
                incomingData = tbuff;

                receiveData(socket, incomingData);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void receiveData(Socket socket, byte[] data) {
    int lenLo = (int) (data[0]);
    int lenHi = (int) (data[1]);
    int length = lenHi * 256 + lenLo;


    if(lenHi < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Packet Length");
    }

    if(data.length != length) {
        System.out.println("Incomplete Packet Received");
    }

    serverGUI.serverDebug("DATA RECEIVED");
    serverGUI.serverDebug(Hex.encodeHexString(data)); //this is the java ouput above serverGUI is simply a jframe i built no data manipulation
    serverGUI.serverDebug("DATA_RECEIVED DONE");
    this.relay.sendData(data); //this function sends the data from socket server to the python asyncio server
}

public void receiveDataFromPythonRelay(Socket socket, byte[] data) {
    serverGUI.debugPythonRelay("DATA RECEIVED");
    serverGUI.debugPythonRelay(Hex.encodeHexString(data)); //this will be the output from the python script aka data decrypted. 
//The data byte[] is created in the exact same way the incomingData array is built in the AuthServer run function
    serverGUI.debugPythonRelay("DATA_RECEIVED DONE");
}
```

Additionally the way I am importing the data byte[] from sockets is programmed as such because the client does not send endl therefore readLine will not work from the streams.

Answer (score 0):

A byte has 8 bits which means you can have maximum 0xff as value.

But Java uses signed byte which means msb is reserved for signed bit. This leaves you with only 7 bits for your value, so you can have maximum as 0x7f stored in byte type of variable. Any number greater than 0x07f will result in overflow.

Try using an int array. As int uses 4 bytes (32 bits) hence there will always be space for 8 bits.

use byte[] to read from the stream and then copy the contents in int[] , Use `int intArr[i] = byteArr[i] & 0xFF;` for ith value from byte[] to avoid negative numbers due to byte overflow

Comment: I haven't gotten home to test this yet will post an update when I get the chance, though given that both the hex printouts are identical in length could this still be the issue?

Comment: Sure, also I have edited my answer as how to read from the byte[] to int[]. I hope you will get some help.